# O_Direct in my.ini startup crash

Tags: mysql, sql-server, innodb

I am searching high and low to solve our database speed problem.

When I try to use:

innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT

In my my.ini file, the MySQL service fails to start. I can not find anywhere on Google where others are having this same error.

Can anyone tell me how I can get this directive to work?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the filename `my.ini` you specified, I have to assume you're on Windows. The `O_DIRECT` option is only available on Linux, FreeBSD, and Solaris. See the [MySQL manual section on `innodb_flush_method`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method) for more details.